# Check if json document contains value

Tags: json, qt

I have the following json file

```
{
   "id":12345,
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "result":{
      "item":{
         "fanart":"",
         "id":999,
         "label":"xyz",
         "thumbnail":"image:",
         "title":"xyz",
         "type":"channel"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I check in QT language if the file contains the key "type" and how can i get the value of it?

This is my solution

> resultJSONDocument.object().value("result").toVariant().toMap().contains("type")

Is there any better solution??

Comment: You can start by reading the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html). If you have difficulty after trying it yourself, come back and show us what you tried.

Comment: I see that you are asking several questions about JSON, IMHO do not use Qt for that since QJsonDocument is not a good option since it does not have many specialized methods like the one you want, instead use other libraries like https://www.google.com/search?q=json+c%2B%2B+github

Comment: It's added...sorry I missed it